# Style row/column/class for json output with Foundation Framework

Tags: jquery, json, zurb-foundation, getjson

TOTAL newbie here... so bear with me.

I've got my json file and output working, and now I need some help to style it the way I want using Foundation Framework.

Say my json file is something like this:

```
{"quotes":[
    {
    "department": "Design",
    "feedback": "Blah Blah Blah",
    "process": "Yes",
    "culture": "No"
    },
    {
    "department": "HR",
    "feedback": "Blah Blah Blah",
    "process": "Yes",
    "culture": "Yes"
    }
]}
```

I can get each quote to display as a paragraph or list item, but I really want each quote to appear on a separate panel (http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/panels.html) - so each one something like:

```
<div class="panel">
    <h2>Design</h2>
    <p>Blah Blah Blah</p>
    <p>Yes</p>
    <p>No</p>
</div>
```

The thing I can't figure out for the life of me is if I have 200 quotes, how do I set the panels to appear either spanning 3 or 4 columns to a row on 'large' screens, and 1 to a row on 'small'? e.g.

```
<div class="row>
    <div class="small-12 large-4 columns">
        <div class="panel>
        *Quote 1*
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 large-4 columns">
        <div class="panel>
        *Quote 2*
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 large-4 columns">
        <div class="panel>
        *Quote 3*
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row>
    <div class="small-12 large-4 columns">
        <div class="panel>
        *Quote 4* yada yada
```

I can create multiple panels in a column easy enough, but have no idea how to make them run across and then generate a new row div when the total columns in a row hits 12.

Any help would be really appreciated... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to just not create a new `row` div and put all the panels in one single `row`. Whenever the amount of columns exceeds 12 they will automatically continue on a new line, and you don't have to dynamically create a new row div.

This might be a bit 'dirty', but in my experience sometimes you have to bend the rules of a framework a bit instead of bending your site in all kinds of shapes just to adhere to a the rules of a tool that is supposed to be helping you.

See: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/vawakobizega/1/)